# Restart a generator by delegating to itself in the end

Tags: javascript, generator

I am wondering about the drawbacks of restarting a generator by delegating to itself in the end.

```js
 function* myGenerator(){
   yield "value1";
   yield "value2";
   yield "value3";
   yield "value4";
   yield* myGenerator();
 }

 const generate = myGenerator();

for (let i = 0; i<15; i++){
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += generate.next().value + "["+i +"]"+"<br />";
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

One drawback that came up to my mind is the possibility of an **infinite loop** if it is used as an iterator. It can be bypassed with a counter, though.

```js
function* myGenerator(c){
  let counter = c? c: 0;
  yield "value1";
  yield "value2";
  yield "value3";
  yield "value4";
  counter++;
  if (counter < 3){
    yield* myGenerator(counter);
  }
}

const generate = myGenerator();

for (let val of generate){
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += val+ "<br />";
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The recursive calls will consume the call stack, and at every yield this stack must be saved and restored.

Your example is a case of tail recursion, so it is easy to rewrite as a loop:

```js
function* myGenerator() {
  while (true) {
    yield "value1";
    yield "value2";
    yield "value3";
    yield "value4";
  }
}

const generate = myGenerator();

for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += generate.next().value + "[" + i + "]<br>";
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

As to avoiding that you try to consume an infinite series, you could use a generic function for that.

Unrelated, but I'd only assign once to `innerHTML`:

```js
function* myGenerator() {
  while (true) {
    yield "value1";
    yield "value2";
    yield "value3";
    yield "value4";
  }
}

function* islice(iterator, count) {
  for (let value of iterator) {
    if (--count < 0) return;
    yield value;
  }
}

const generate = islice(myGenerator(), 15);

const values = Array.from(generate, (value, i) => value + "[" + i + "]");
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += values.join("<br>");
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is apparent that generators are not meant for this. Maybe, keeping the values in an array and mode of the counter with respect to the size of the array will be handy to get the desired member of the array.

Comment: *"It is apparent that generators are not meant for this"*: why not?

Comment: Of course, it can be used. It requires an indirect path to implement. It is a little hard for old schoolers to think in terms of functional programming, I guess. At least I personally need some time to digest it.

Comment: OK, *"a little hard"* is a different assessment than *"not meant for this"*. I don't see why you would conclude the latter. Not sure what you mean with "indirect path". `yield` seems quite direct to me.

Comment: I changed the wording. Could have been more careful about the wording. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Another case of inifity loop / Stackoverflow:

```
        function* myGenerator() {
            // when nothing to yield temply
            yield* myGenerator();
        }
```

2. Bad for GC, too many instance created.

```js
        var cur_counter = 0;
        function* myGenerator() {
            cur_counter++;
            console.log("current count of generator: " + cur_counter);
            yield 1;
            yield* myGenerator();
            cur_counter--; // will never be called
        }
```

**EDIT**

Callstack:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I thought, it is going to point to itself and live with a single instance. Old school workarounds look safer.

Comment: @YavuzT I'm not particularly clear about the implementation principle of JS interpreter, but from the results of debugger, it seems that the stack is growing. (debugger screenshot is appended to my answer.)

Comment: Thank you. This can be avoided in alternative implementations. Can be used if stack size is not an issue.